# Поиск фразы через регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, python, php, регулярные-выражения

помогите поправить регулярное выражение

Нужно что бы регулярка по частичному вводу строки находила полную фразу. Папример, мы ввели   "умен напи yml". Регулярка должна найти "умение написать yml"

Вот пример регулярки и теста в котором нужно искать https://regex101.com/r/3PzF5p/1

Comment: `"умен.+? напи.+? yml.+?"`?

Comment: Она находит лишнее, я так уже пробовал, мне нужно что бы нашел именно строку "умение написать yml" по "умен напи yml"

Comment: Так? `(умен[^\s]*?)\s?(напи[^\s]*?)\s(yml.*?\s)`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3PzF5p/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавьте `\w*` после каждого начала слова (при условии, что в словах только буквы или цифры), разделите слова пробельным символом `\s`:

```
   (умен\w*)\s(напи\w*)\s(yml\w*)
```

Если под словами понимается последовательность чего угодно, кроме пробельных символов, то можно так:

```
   (умен\S*)\s(напи\S*)\s(yml\S*)
```

Скобки можно убрать, они здесь для лучшей читаемости.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно